# Time complexity of isRotation algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, time, time-complexity

This common code is said to run in O(N) time assuming isSubstring runs in O(N+M) time.
How do we get O(N) time complexity from this?

```
    public static boolean isRotation(String s1, String s2) {
        int len = s1.length();
        if (len == s2.length() && len > 0) { 
            String s1s1 = s1 + s1;
            return isSubstring(s1s1, s2);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to see why you think it *wouldn't* be O(N) time.

Comment: Remember that O(N+M) *is* O(N)

Comment: "isSubstring runs in O(N+M) time" means "isSubstring(s, t) runs in O(len(s) + len(t)) time". I think you're confused because you're using N to mean two different things: the length of the input strings if they're equal), but also the length of an argument to isSubstring.

Answer (score -1):

Usually when we say linear it means that with really really big number of basic operations our algorithm still performs in *O(n)*. According to time complexity calculation of [sublinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Sub-linear_time) function like *O(n+m)* complexity gets pretty randomized but behaves like linear with large N. So generally we can say *O(n)~O(n+m)*.

[image]